# MonoGame NullReferenceException on iOS

Tags: f#, xamarin.ios, monogame

I'm trying to build a simple MonoGame app for iOS using F#. I have done this by manually cooking up a `fsproj` file, on the basis of project files for

- F# iOS Single Page Application (template),
- F# console application (template) and
- C# iOS MonoGame (template).

My code looks like this:

```
namespace MonoGameFSharpTemplate

module Game =
    open Microsoft.Xna.Framework
    open Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics
    open Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input
    open Microsoft.Devices.Sensors

    type Game1 () as x =
        inherit Game()

        do x.Content.RootDirectory <- "Content"
        member val graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(x) with get, set

        override x.Initialize() =
            do base.Initialize()

        override x.LoadContent() = ()

        override x.Update (gameTime) =
            do base.Update(gameTime)

        override x.Draw (gameTime) =
            do base.Draw(gameTime)

module App =
    open UIKit
    open Foundation
    open Game

    [<Register("AppDelegate")>]
    type AppDelegate() =
        inherit UIApplicationDelegate()

        override val Window = null with get, set

        override this.FinishedLaunching(app, options) =
            use game = new Game1()
            game.Run()
            true

module Main =
    open UIKit

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv = 
        UIApplication.Main(argv, null, "AppDelegate")
        0
```

It should be pretty much equivalent to the code provided in the C# template (which runs just fine, by the way).

When running this code in the iOS simulator, I get a `NullReferenceException` with the following stack trace

```
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.get_IsActive () [0x00000] in <d3066bb8224f42c4ab3ae66d66329856>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.iOSGamePlatform.Tick () [0x00006] in <d3066bb8224f42c4ab3ae66d66329856>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.iOSGameView.DoTick () [0x00000] in <d3066bb8224f42c4ab3ae66d66329856>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5024/152b654a/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5024/152b654a/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
  at MonoGameFSharpTemplate.Main.main (System.String[] argv) [0x00000] in /Users/torbonde/Projects/MonoGameFSharpTemplate/MonoGameFSharpTemplate/Program.fs:47
```

I'm running the latest MonoGame build, v3.7.0.937, but I had the same issue using v3.6.

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error, and how to fix it? I can post the project file with references if necessary.

Comment: As the source code is available, https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Game.cs#L212 you might do some analysis. I suggest you report a new issue with enough information at GitHub and reach out to the developers directly.